# grep out rows where value is greater than say 50 in certain column

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm a beginner and learning about grep so here goes my question.  Using Linux, I want to stout rows from a file that only shows what I specified for.  For instance some column shows a time duration in secs, and I want to show only those rows where the seconds are more than 50 secs. I can figure out how many rows by using cut/sort/uniq/sort but it's not as useful as having the entire row of info at the same time.  Here is just an example.  I want to grab the rows with only time greater than 13.9 secs.

```
64 bytes from hugs05s22-in-f8.1e100.net (100.100.239.204): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=13.9 ms 
64 bytes from hugs05s22-in-f8.1e100.net (100.100.239.204): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=13.2 ms
64 bytes from hugs05s22-in-f8.1e100.net (100.100.239.204): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=13.9 ms
64 bytes from hugs05s22-in-f8.1e100.net (100.100.239.204): icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=18.3 ms
64 bytes from hugs05s22-in-f8.1e100.net (100.100.239.204): icmp_seq=5 ttl=55 time=14.3 ms
64 bytes from hugs05s22-in-f8.1e100.net (100.100.239.204): icmp_seq=6 ttl=55 time=17.7 ms
64 bytes from hugs05s22-in-f8.1e100.net (100.100.239.204): icmp_seq=7 ttl=55 time=13.4 ms
```

I would be able to pull out the entire row with 18.3/14.3/17.7 (lets say that time= wasn't part of the column (or for the heck of it was as well)).  Any help in awk, sed, or just grep would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions are not appropriate for numeric comparisons (you could do it, but it would be cumbersome). Use `awk`, it has arithmetic operators.

```
awk -F'[ =]' '$11 > 50'
```

Comment: Thank you, Barmar. Someone had shown me using grep but I didn't get a chance to write it down and learn from it. So like how calculus was taught, the teachers teach you the hard stuff until the very end they show you how much easier it could be. Using the grep way would be more of a learning experience aside from your great answer.